# End to End testing for Multipart data

Tags: typescript, loopback

**I have working REST API in Loopback framework. In that I have POST method where I am accepting one payload and 3 different files. Code looks like this**

```
@post("/v1/api/order", {
    responses: {
      200: {
        content: {
          "application/json": { schema: { "x-ts-type": Order } },
          "multipart/mixed": {
            "x-parser": "stream",
            schema: { type: "object" }
          }
        },
        description: "Order model instance"
      }
    }
  })

  public async createOrder(
    @requestBody({
      content: {
        "multipart/form-data": {
          "x-parser": "stream",
          schema: { type: "object" }
        }
      },
      description: "multipart/form-data value.",
      required: true
    })
    request: Request,
    @inject(RestBindings.Http.RESPONSE) response: Response): Promise<any> {
    this.logger.info(`createOrder`, { userId: "loggedOn User", method: "createOrder" });


    const fileUpload = new FileUploader();
    const aHelper = new AttachmentHelper();

    const results: any = await fileUpload
      .multerFileUpload(request, response)
      .then((result: any) => {

        return {
          attachmentDetails: aHelper.attachmentInformation(result),
          orderDetails: _.get(result.fields, "payload")
        };
      })
      .catch((err: Error) => {
        response.status(400);
        this.logger.error("createOrder", err.stack, "error occured while create order");
        throw err;
      });
```

**I am writing End to End testing but not able to send payload using send method. I am using testlab. Can anyone please suggest how to write test case for this.**

```
it.only('Insert the order', async () => {
        const neworder = givenNewOrderPayload();

        console.log("New Order Payload.", neworder);

        await client.post(`/v1/api/order`)
        .set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')
        .set(neworder)
        .expect(200)
}



 function givenNewOrderPayload() {
        let userInput = a;
        return {'payload': userInput}
    }
```

**I am expecting data to be inserted in database with 200 status code.
Actual Result: 400 Bad Request**

Answer (score 1):

> I am writing End to End testing but not able to send payload using send method. I am using testlab.

LoopBack's `testlab` module is exposing [`supertest`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest) under the hood, which uses [`superagent`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent) as the HTTP client library.

To send a multi-part request uploading a file, you should use `attach` method as described in [their docs](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#multipart-requests).

See also how LoopBack is testing file uploads internally, e.g. in [`packages/rest/src/__tests__/acceptance/file-upload/file-upload.acceptance.ts`](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/97c01b77fa8872af7e9f09c5abc061b6377c29a5/packages/rest/src/__tests__/acceptance/file-upload/file-upload.acceptance.ts#L32-L48):

```
  it('supports file uploads', async () => {
    const FIXTURES = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../../fixtures');
    const res = await client
      .post('/show-body')
      .field('user', 'john')
      .field('email', 'john@example.com')
      .attach('testFile', path.resolve(FIXTURES, 'file-upload-test.txt'), {
        filename: 'file-upload-test.txt',
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
      })
      .expect(200);
    expect(res.body.files[0]).containEql({
      fieldname: 'testFile',
      originalname: 'file-upload-test.txt',
      mimetype: 'multipart/form-data',
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thank You! I will try this.

Comment: I tried with this one but getting following error
  Error: expected 200 "OK", got 500 "Internal Server Error"

Comment: I can confirm, this solution is working. Thank you @M.R